# ConTeXt: Avoid extra line from figure in itemize

Tags: spacing, context, itemize

Constructing exams I often want to put figures close to the problem text. Perhaps I am doing something in a bad way, but the naive way adding a right-aligned figure does give an extra, unwanted, line. See the example below, where the extra line is added in the second item.

```
\setuppapersize[A6]
\starttext
\startitemize[n]
\item \input ward
\item 
\startplacefigure[location={right,nonumber}]%
\blackrule[width=1in,height=1in]
\stopplacefigure
\input ward
\stopitemize
\stoptext
```

[image: output with an extra line in the second item]

> **Question**: Is there a generic way to get rid of that extra line? If not, is there a "hacky" way of getting rid of it?

I have tried to add a `\blank[overlay]` (that sometimes works fine in nested itemizes when the same problem show up), but it did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the `placefigure` environment before the second `item` entry.

```
\setuppapersize[A6]

\starttext

\startitemize[n]

\startitem
  \input ward
\stopitem

\startplacefigure[location={right,nonumber}]%
  \blackrule[width=1in,height=1in]
\stopplacefigure

\startitem 
  \input ward
\stopitem

\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! I just realized I first read your change wrongly and perhaps accepted the answer although there is a problem with this. Your solution actually kills the vertical space between the itemizes. This is not a problem if one uses the `packed` option to itemize, but is there a way (other than the hackish one posted by @henrikmenke) to not change the space between the items.

Comment: @mickep The vertical space (which is inserted by `\startitem`) before the second item was removed by the side float. One solution to get the space back is to add a `\blank` command before `\startplacefigure`. Another way to get it back is to add a space before each side float with `\setupfloats[spacebeforeside=big]`, to keep this setting local you can add it after `\startitemize`.

Comment: Thank you! This really solves my problem. I tried to define my own float and to use `\setupfloat` on just that float, but that did not seem to work. In any case, I now have a way to tune this to fit my needs (the exams are pretty small documents, so the question of global setting is not a problem). Again, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is the hacky way to get rid of it.  Just place `\blank[-line,force]` in front.  I don't know of a generic way though.

```
\setuppapersize[A6]

\starttext

\startitemize[n]
\item \input ward
\item \blank[-line,force]
  \startplacefigure[location={right,nonumber}]
    \blackrule[width=1in,height=1in]
  \stopplacefigure
  \input ward
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

[image]